# Spring Boot JPA One To Many and Many to One With Multiple Tables

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I have 5 Tables, A User can have many module/role/plant. `user_master` is the main table with user details and user_roles is the sub table with module/role/plant details. My doubt is how to write the relationship in Model Class.

```
user_master
------------
user_id int(10) unsigned
first_name  varchar(50)
last_name   varchar(50)
mail_id varchar(80)
user_status tinyint(4)
is_deleted  tinyint(4)
created_by  int(10)
created_date    date
modified_by int(10)
modified_date   date

user_roles
-----------
user_role_id    int(10) unsigned
user_id int(10) unsigned
module_master_id    int(10) unsigned
role_master_id  int(10) unsigned
plant_master_id int(10) unsigned

module_master:
module_master_id    int(10) unsigned
module_code int(10)
module_name varchar(50)
active_flag tinyint(4)

role_master:
role_master_id  int(10) unsigned
module_master_id    int(10) unsigned
role_code   int(10)
role_name   varchar(50)
active_flag tinyint(4)

plant_master:
plant_master_id int(10) unsigned
plant_code  int(10)
plant_name  varchar(50)
active_flag tinyint(4)
```

The remaining module/role/plant have their own masters, `master_id` are primary key to master tables.

I just want to write `user_master` and `user_roles` model class. One-to-many & many-to-one mapping is required.

Answer (score 0):

For one to many, you can have like below in your entity class:

1. `@OneToMany` in user entity

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   private List<Role> roles;
   ```
2. `@ManyToOne` at roles side

   ```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user")
   private User user;
   ```

   **@ManyToMany**

   ```
   @ManyToMany(cascade = { 
       CascadeType.PERSIST, 
       CascadeType.MERGE
   })
   @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
   )
   private List<Role> roles= new ArrayList<>();
   ```

and role side:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

here is an example to have many to many with emdeded:

```
    @Entity
    public class UserRoleMaster implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRoleMasterId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_master_id", referencedColumnName = "user_master_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserMaster userMaster;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_roles_id", referencedColumnName = "user_roles_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserRoles userRoles;

    //getter  //setter //constructures

       @Embeddable
       public static class UserRoleMasterId implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "user_master_id")
        protected Long userMasterId;

        @Column(name = "user_roles_id")
        protected Long userRolesId;
       //constrcture //getter //setters
   }
 }
```

Comment: In user_roles model, I want to associate module_master primary_key & other masters primary keys also

Comment: I've user_master & user_roles table. User_master will be having user data and user_roles will have various master primary_key. for example module_master_id,role_master_id & plant_master_id, each master have their own models . I dont know how to associate between user_master and user_roles.

Comment: You can create seprate entity for it with embedded key